# Highlight colored syntax off when refresh in vim issue

Tags: vim

Currently I'm using ctags and highlighting colored syntax in vim.
but problem is that the colored syntax highlighting off when I refresh the vim window with "e!".

my .vimrc is

```
syntax on

set exrc

set ruler

set exrc

au BufNewFile, BufRead *.sv, *.v so ~/.vim/syntax/verilogsystemverilog.vim
```

Would you please help me what problem makes this happen?

Answer (score 0):

That autocmd as written shouldn't work at all. There must not be any whitespace inside the `{event}` and `{pat}` enumerations:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sv,*.v so ~/.vim/syntax/verilogsystemverilog.vim
```

Additionally, you're circumventing Vim's *filetype* mechanism completely. Even if you don't use *filetype plugins* (which can supply specific indent, formatting, etc. settings and mappings), it's advisable to follow that mechanism.

To enable this, put `filetype on` in your `~/.vimrc`. Then (following [`:help new-filetype`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype)), create a custom detection `~/.vim/ftdetect/verilogsystemverilog.vim` with the following contents:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sv,*.v setfiletype verilogsystemverilog
```

This will automatically set `'syntax'`, and with that, loads your syntax script (from `~/.vim/syntax/verilogsystemverilog.vim`, but without having you specify the full path directly).

---

PS: You have `set exrc` twice, and you could even combine all into a single command `set exrc ruler`.